# Inflation Exception on clicking an icon

Tags: java, android, android-layout, binary-xml

I am trying to put display a `popup menu` every time a user clicks on the `button` in the bottom right corner of a `card`, but every time I click on this `button`, I get this error :

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x6db "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_dots.png" a=4 r=0x7f080080}

I thought the error was maybe because I put the wrong icon in the wrong folder so I tried to put all the icons in the correct drawable folder, like `drawable-hdpi`,`drawable-mdpi`,`drawable-xhdpi`,drawable-xxhdpi`,`drawable-xxxhdpi`but it did not work. The`logcat` and the code is given below :

**Logcat**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x6db "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_dots.png" a=4 r=0x7f080080}
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:169)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:203)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:288)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:141)
       at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:233)
       at Adapter.CourseAdapter.showPopupMenu(CourseAdapter.java:70)
       at Adapter.CourseAdapter.access$000(CourseAdapter.java:26)
       at Adapter.CourseAdapter$1.onClick(CourseAdapter.java:56)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5269)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21556)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x6db "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_dots.png" a=4 r=0x7f080080}
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:705)
       at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7094)
       at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7275)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:506)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:446)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:445)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93) 
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160) 
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:169) 
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:203) 
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:288) 
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175) 
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:141) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:233) 
       at Adapter.CourseAdapter.showPopupMenu(CourseAdapter.java:70) 
       at Adapter.CourseAdapter.access$000(CourseAdapter.java:26) 
       at Adapter.CourseAdapter$1.onClick(CourseAdapter.java:56) 
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5269) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21556) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

**Code**

```
public class CourseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Courses> coursesList;

    public CourseAdapter(Context mContext, List<Courses> coursesList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.coursesList = coursesList;
    }

    @Override
    public CourseAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.courses_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CourseAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Courses album = coursesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getName());
        holder.subtext.setText(album.getSubtext());

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_course, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }

    /**
     * Click listener for popup menu items
     */
    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_apply:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Apply", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return coursesList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, subtext;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            subtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtext);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }
}
```

The `logcat` indicates the error is in the method `showPopupMenu(View view)`

The `xml` file for `popup menu` is given below :

**menu_course**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_apply"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Apply" />

</menu>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: maybe in your layout, check the `R.menu.menu_course` layout

Comment: I have added the `xml` file

Comment: Check your theme for appCompat theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
mContext.getMenuInflater();
```

instead of

```
popup.getMenuInflater();
```